# codeigniter mail attachment corrupted

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-attachments

using `codeigniter 1.5.2` framework,i try to upload file send as an attachment in mail but when mail send it shows **.dat** file and not relevant to file I send.

```
$attachfilepath = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$attachfilename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$CI->load->library('email');
$CI->email->from($adminemail, 'Client Name');
$CI->email->to($to);
$CI->email->subject($subject);
$CI->email->message($message);
$CI->email->attach($attachfilepath,$attachfilename);
$CI->email->send();
```

P.S- i heard this versions attachment function is not stable but attachment function is working when give local file

Comment: thank you @PrasadKhode for edit the questions :)

Comment: I also have the very same question...looking for an answer in a rush.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@bhugy I think this is some bus of the codeigniter version.
we cant use temp file save path in this version of codeigniter.but we can use this logic when we use pure php. *(may be new version of codeigniter)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can attach files in that way.

I can't specifically find the old 1.5.2 code so I cannot 100% confirm this

`attach($filename, $disposition = 'attachment')`

^^ this is the method signature from the Email library 2.x

`attach($attachfilepath, $attachfilename);`

^^ You are not doing it correctly.

I think you need to do.

`$attachedFileLocation = $attachfilepath . $attachfilename
$CI->email->attach($attachedFileLocation);`

^^ you may need to add a forward slash between the 2 so that it creates a full path but that is something you will have to debug.

Hopefully this sorts your issue.

P.S. I would also suggest upgrading to CI 2 because there are not that many breaking changes between the 2 version but many minor issues were addressed.

Comment: no. its not working. i try this before. :(
<br/><br/>
thank you for reply mic :)

Comment: if you open the email library and go to the attach method what does it say?

Comment: its okay I found the 1.5.2 source... its exactly the same as the one I found in the 2.x code `function attach($filename, $disposition = 'attachment')`. This means that the way your attaching your file is incorrect.

Comment: `function attach($filename, $disposition = 'attachment')
 {   
  $this->_attach_name[] = $filename;
  $this->_attach_type[] = $this->_mime_types(next(explode('.', basename($filename))));
  $this->_attach_disp[] = $disposition; // Can also be 'inline'  Not sure if it matters
 }`

Comment: its work on local file.  `$CI->email->attach('/web/html/sidweb2/cuploads/eee.txt')`  this code is working.but i have to attach without saving upload file. :(

Comment: Okay, so i was right about the first issue. You were not putting the correct parameters in to the method. If it is having issues reading a file that has been saved to a location, it might be a permissions issue. Try attaching the saved image and echoing the print_debugger() method so you can see why it has failed. Also check that the image is actually saved in the expected location.